# save a function in localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm working with some objects that contains a number of data to be displayed and manipulated from browser, and I want to save it in local storage.
In order to save objects I used JSON.stringify() so everything become text, and it works well

```
{
"bindingRef": [],
"primo": {
    "name": "primo",
    "modifiable": true,
    "binded": false,
    "isInteger": false,
    "label": "Numero di Primi"
},
"secondo": {
    "name": "secondo",
    "modifiable": true,
    "binded": false,
    "isInteger": false,
    "label": "Numero di Secondi"
}
}
```

Now I'm trying to save also a function by converting it to a string and then saveing it

```
JSON.stringify(myFunction.toString());
```

but the output is this

```
"savedFunction": "function () {\n\t\t\t\tvar tot = menu.primo.get() * 6 + menu.secondo.get() * 8 + menu.dolce.get() * 4;\n\t\t\t\tif (menu.sconto.get()) {\n\t\t\t\t\treturn tot * 0.90;\n\t\t\t\t} else {\n\t\t\t\t\treturn tot;\n\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t}"
```

Is it the correct way to save a function in local storage or is there a better way to do this? If this is the correct way, is there a way to simply remove any tabulation/indentation character or should I manipulate the string, for example using some regexp function?

Comment: You want to save object stringified or function signature ? What output are you expecting ?

Comment: Why do you want to save a function? In my opinion there is no "correct" way to do this because it doesn't really make sense to do it at all. Assuming you do want to save the `.toString()` version of the function, why do you want to remove tabs (which you could do with `.replace()`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function in JS as in many functional languages are closures: they wrap inside them the content of the environment scope at the moment of definition, including ephemeral data like db or file handles.

It's not a good idea because this can lead to problems due to JSON deserialization behaviour, so you have to check what in the function is wrapped and what is self-defined.

See also this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955965/how-come-json-cant-save-objects-functions) for further information.

Comment: useful link and useful answer, I'll try to avoid saving a function. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can put the function in an object and use the functions storage.set and storage.get that I created instead of localStorage.set and localStorage.get *(localStorage doesn't allow functions to be added, unlike JSON)*.

storage.set will stringify an object including functions before using localStorage.setItem().
storage.get will parse an object including functions after using localStorage.getItem().

I modified the functions JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to be able to handle functions, so you can use it in other parts of your code without changing function names. I appended a 2 to the original functions, so I can use them within the updated functions.

```
JSON.stringify2 = JSON.stringify;
JSON.parse2 = JSON.parse;

JSON.stringify = function(value) {
    return JSON.stringify2(value, function(key, val) {
        return (typeof val === 'function') ? val.toString().replace(/\t|\n/g, '') : val;
    });
}

JSON.parse = function(value) {
    return JSON.parse2(value, function(key, val) {
        if (typeof val === 'string') {
            var regex = /^function\s*\([^()]*\)\s*{.*}$/;

            if (regex.exec(val) !== null)
                return eval('key = ' + val);
            else
                return val;
        } else
            return val;
    });
}

var storage = {};

storage.set = function(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object')
        value = JSON.stringify(value);

    localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}

storage.get = function(key) {
    var value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    try {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding natives is a bad practice. Consider creating new functions instead.