# How to call parent window function on child window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want call a javascript function defined in parent on child window.
I have searched for window.opener and window.parent, but they call function on parent window not on child.
Also if it is possible by local storage.
Parent window function:

```
var myFunction=function download() {
        console.log("in jsp download")
        $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            //some operation
        });
    }

    window.onload = function() {
        localStorage.setItem("storageName",myfunction);

    }
```

Child window

```
<button id="exportExcel" onclick="localStorage.getItem("storageName")">Export</button>
```

But this is giving error on child window

Comment: What do you mean by "on child window"? It sounds like you actually just want to pass a parameter.

Comment: I don't think it's good idea to store a function in localstorage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063630/save-a-function-in-localstorage

Comment: I meant that I want to run parent javascript function on child page not parent page.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the function you're attaching it to the parent's scope. If the parent page opens the child (via `window.open`) you can access its scope through the child's `window.opener` object.

**Parent Page**

```
Function DoSomething(){}
```

**Child Page**

```
window.opener.DoSomething()
```

Comment: you are right, that function is visible, but it is running on parent screen, I want to run it on child screen.